# Show properties of class in consol Javascript

Tags: javascript

How to Show properties of class in consol Javascript

```
Class MyClass {
 public name;
 public id;
}
```

and i have this

```
var user = new MyClass()
```

Comment: The above is a syntax error; `Class` should be `class`, case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your class to

```
class myclass{
 constructor(name, id) {
    this.name= name;
    this.id= id;
  }
}
// user of it 
 var user = new myclass("Jon ace",1);
 console.log(user);
```

Comment: thank you , but how about declaring the properties ?

Comment: read this [Classes on mozilla web site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 1):

The below is what you're looking for, using the Object.keys method.

```
class MyClass {
 constructor(name, id) {
   this.name = name;
   this.id = id;
 }
}
var user = new MyClass('a',1)
console.log(Object.keys(user))
```